# Maximum number of partitions in hive

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

I have 1500 partition in my hive tables but while doing query it is taking more time then expected.
Maximum number of partitions can be created in hive table.

Comment: Please give more description of your question. like sample code, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Current Hive versions with RDBMS metastore backend should be able to handle `10000+` partitions.

For numerous reasons, the community is moving away from this design to leverage HBase for the metastore. Follow 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9452 .

Overall design document is available here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12697601/HBaseMetastoreApproach.pdf

Comment: Go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103221/partitioning-in-hive