# Maximum number of databases and tables in Hive Metastore

Tags: hadoop, hive

Inspired by a formerly asked question:
[Maximum number of partitions in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929916/maximum-number-of-partitions-in-hive)

I would like to know if there is also maximum number for items below:

1. Maximum number of databases in a catalog (I assume Hive Metastore only has one catalog, which is "hive")
2. Maximum number of tables per database (as in, can I create 10 million tables in a database or due to limitation must I split them into 10 databases each with 1 million tables)

I also would like to know whether the limitations are hard limit (unconfigurable), or configurable by Hive, or dependent on RDBMS it is using.

UPDATE:
Crossposted to [Cloudera Community](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Max-number-of-databases-and-tables-allowed-in-Hive-Metastore/td-p/351053) after 7 days of inactivity. I will be active on both places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in [Cloudera Community](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Max-number-of-databases-and-tables-allowed-in-Hive-Metastore/m-p/351061/highlight/true#M236135) by [ChethanYM](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/75213)

Key Summary:

- No hard limits on database and tables
- Expect performance issues if total number of objects exceeds 500,000 (defined as "objects like tables and partitions in the warehouse including column and column type information etc...")